# Remove focus from Entry widget

Tags: python, tkinter

I have simple example, Entry and three separate Frames.

```
from tkinter import *

top = Tk()

Entry(top, width="20").pack()
Frame(top, width=200, height=200, bg='blue').pack()
Frame(top, width=200, height=200, bg='green').pack()
Frame(top, width=200, height=200, bg='yellow').pack() 
# Some extra widgets   
Label(top, width=20, text='Label text').pack()
Button(top, width=20, text='Button text').pack()

top.mainloop()
```

Once I start writing in Entry, the keyboard cursor stay there, even when I press with mouse on blue, green or yellow Frame. How to stop writing in Entry, when mouse presses another widget? In this example only three widgets except Entry. But assume there is alot of widgets.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By default, `Frames` do not take keyboard focus.  However, if you want to give them keyboard focus when clicked on, you can do so by binding the `focus_set` method to a mouse click event:

## Option 1

```
from tkinter import *

top = Tk()

Entry(top, width="20").pack()
b = Frame(top, width=200, height=200, bg='blue')
g = Frame(top, width=200, height=200, bg='green')
y = Frame(top, width=200, height=200, bg='yellow')

b.pack()
g.pack()
y.pack()

b.bind("<1>", lambda event: b.focus_set())
g.bind("<1>", lambda event: g.focus_set())
y.bind("<1>", lambda event: y.focus_set())

top.mainloop()
```

Note that to do this you'll need to keep references to your widgets, as I did above with the variables `b`, `g`, and `y`.

---

## Option 2

Here is another solution, accomplished by creating a subclass of `Frame` that is able to take keyboard focus:

```
from tkinter import *

class FocusFrame(Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.bind("<1>", lambda event: self.focus_set())

top = Tk()

Entry(top, width="20").pack()
FocusFrame(top, width=200, height=200, bg='blue').pack()
FocusFrame(top, width=200, height=200, bg='green').pack()
FocusFrame(top, width=200, height=200, bg='yellow').pack()    

top.mainloop()
```

---

## Option 3

A third option is to just use `bind_all` to make every single widget take the keyboard focus when clicked (or you can use `bind_class` if you only want certain types of widgets to do this).

Just add this line:

```
top.bind_all("<1>", lambda event:event.widget.focus_set())
```

Comment: Thank you. But is there global solution? Like I said, assume there is lots of widgets, not only three.

Comment: Sure. Posted another solution - does that fit what you're looking for?

Comment: @Brionius Iteresting problem. I edited the question, as I think OP asks for very general solution.

Comment: Added third solution which the OP might like better if they want widgets other than Frames to exhibit this behavior.

Comment: Option 3 was very helpful. Thanks!