# How to correctly remove focus from entry when checkbutton is selected?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have seen [some answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24072567/remove-focus-from-entry-widget) on SO, however, it does not seem to be the right solution for the use case.
In this example I need to remove focus, disable the Entry and remove its contents when checkbutton is clicked:

```py
from tkinter import *


root = Tk()

def manage_entry():
    if bool(var.get()) == False:
        e.config(state = 'normal')

    if bool(var.get()) == True:
        e.delete(0, END)
        e.config(state = 'disabled')
        # this is not great, but removes focus when checkbutton selected
        root.focus()


var = BooleanVar()
var_c = Checkbutton(root, text = 'Freeze entry', variable = var, command = manage_entry)
var_c.deselect()
var_c.pack()

e = Entry(root, width = 15)
e.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

When checkbutton clicked focus is set to the Tk() which produces what I need but seems incorrect usage of the method. It's for sure a workaround but is there a more correct way to disable the focus? I have also tried `e.config(takefocus = 0)` but this did not remove the focus

Comment: Why do you think it is not great?

Comment: The entry will lose the focus after it is disabled, even without the line `root.focus()`.  So what do you want exactly?

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA it does not seem the good way to focus on the main window instead of just taking focus off Entry widget when a certain action is made.

Comment: @acw for me on Mac it is not the case. If you click in the Entry and disable it, then focus is still on it. If you focus on a Checkbutton instead of Tk, it will focus on it wraping the text and checkbox with a black line. For sure, one can adjust the color to match the bacground but this is also a workaround.

Comment: Try `e.event_generate('<FocusOut>')` instead of `root.focus()`.